# Taylor expansion on Riemannian manifolds

Tags: taylor-expansion, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curves

Let $f : \mathcal M \to \mathcal N$ be a smooth map between Riemannian maniolds. Suppose also we have a smooth curve $\gamma : (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon) \to \mathcal M$. Can we say that the Taylor expansion of $f$ around $\gamma(0)$ is given by
\begin{align}
(f \circ \gamma)(t) &= (f \circ \gamma)(0) + t(f\circ \gamma)'(0) + \frac{t^2}{2}(f \circ \gamma)''(0) + \dots \ ?
\end{align}
In other words, are the notions of Jacobian and Hessian etc. encoded into the derivatives of $f \circ \gamma$? I suppose you could use the chain rule to expand the derivatives into something like $(f \circ \gamma)'(0) = [ \mathbf J_f(p)]X$, where $\mathbf J_f$ denotes the Jacobian of $f$ and $p = \gamma(0)$ and $X = \gamma'(0)$. Does the above Taylor expansion hold in general for smooth functions and curves on Riemannian manifolds? Also, how does this relate to geodesics and the exponential map?

Comment: Wait a minute. Your function $f$ should take values in $\mathbb R$ (or, more generally, in a vector space). Otherwise, what would $f(\gamma(0)) + ...$ mean? There is no sum in a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Oh wow you're right, I didn't even think about that . What if the manifolds are embedded in Euclidean space though?

Comment: You can of course embed the manifold in Euclidean space and proceed from there. But will that help you do whatever you're trying to do?

Comment: As a more general comment of what you're trying to do, the notion of higher derivatives don't generalize to manifolds in a straightforward way because moving between coordinate charts "mixes" the derivatives of different orders. To deal with this in an intrinsic way, you can use [jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(mathematics)#Jets_of_functions_between_two_manifolds).